# Coinbase API large responses and slow

Tags: node.js, async-await, coinbase-api

The following code takes a good 5 to 10 seconds to resolve (there are 5 API-calls). It's not usable as it is. Is the slow response my fault or is the Coinbase API just slow and large?

```
app.get('/buys', async (req, res) => {
    const buys = await getAllBuys()
    res.json(buys)
})

const fetchAllAccounts = () => {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            coinbase.getAccounts(null, (err, accounts) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
                else{
                    resolve(accounts)
                }
            })
        }
    )
}

const fetchAllBuys = (account) => {

    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            account.getBuys(null, (err, buys) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
                else{
                    resolve(buys)
                }
            })
        }
    )
}


const getAllBuys = async () => {
    const accounts = await fetchAllAccounts()

    let combinedBuys = []

    for (let account of accounts) {
        const buys = await fetchAllBuys(account)
        combinedBuys = [...combinedBuys, ...buys]
    }
    //console.log(combinedBuys)
    return combinedBuys
}
```

Response is a array with items that include account information like certificates and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it was my code. I the code above I wait for each request to finish before firing off a new one. Which results in unnecessary delay. With the `Promise.all` method we can generate all the promises and resolve them at the same time. Look at the refactored code bellow.

```
app.get('/buys', async (req, res) => {
    console.time('[/buys]');

    const promises = await getAllBuys()
    const buys = await Promise.all(promises)
    res.json(buys)

    console.timeEnd('[/buys]');
})


const fetchAllAccounts = () => {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            coinbase.getAccounts(null, (err, accounts) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
                else{
                    resolve(accounts)
                }
            })
        }
    )
}

const fetchAllBuys = (account) => {

    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            account.getBuys(null, (err, buys) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
                else{
                    resolve(buys)
                }
            })
        }
    )
}


const getAllBuys = async () => {
    const accounts = await fetchAllAccounts()

    let promises = []

    for (let account of accounts) {
        promises.push(fetchAllBuys(account))
    }
    return promises
}
```

From 2,5 / 3 seconds to 0,8 / 1 second.